# Missing Driver for Canon Printer

Tags: software-installation, printing

Need to install a driver for a Canon Pixma MG2920 printer to use with a Raspberry Pi 3 as a server.

Followed all the steps listed in a few online tutorials, but the printer is not listed in CUPS. Here is one example:

https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-print-server/

Therefore, looked the driver at Canon’s website and attempted to install the one listed for Debian, but receive the error that is the correct system.

Has anyone used their Raspberry Pi as a printer server?

Wondering if there are any compatible drivers out there for our printer?

Using another driver listed in CUSP, the printer light will flash and the print job will update to completed. So, thinking maybe it needs the driver for its model?

Comment: Unlucky you've got the least supported printer from a company that doesn't care about Linux systems and certainly doesn't care about Linux systems on ARMHF processors. Try the gutenprint drivers.

Comment: Any recommendations for a new printer from a Linux friendly company!

Comment: My HP IPP printer works OK.

Comment: @That's because of [IPP](https://www.cups.org/blog/2018-06-06-demystifying-cups-development.html). The OP's printer lists Windows XP support, so I suppose it doesn't support IPP.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding recommendations for a new printer, take the time to read [this article](https://www.cups.org/blog/2018-06-06-demystifying-cups-development.html) where Apple (the main developer of CUPS) explained their then-recent design decisions. Modern printers are expected to support IPP and need no device-specific driver. That's the number one feature you should look for when buying a new device.

Support for printers using PPD files or raw printer queues was expected to stop between 2018 and 2020, which is now.

Check out [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=219763) if you want to try out `gutenprint` drivers @Dougie mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If the printer is supported for Linux can be verified at **OpenPrinting**.

OpenPrinting have a database over both supported and unsupported, so check out your model here: https://openprinting.github.io/databaseintro/

And the closest model I found is :

[image]

Comment: Nice site, didn't know about it. This is the definitive answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I had luck with gutenprint on the rpi for a cups server, my printer was PIXMA iP2700